# WhatsApp does not vibrate when I get a message

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, whatsapp-messenger, vibration

In Samsung Galaxy Note 2, WhatsApp does not vibrate either in sound mode or vibration mode when I get a message. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings > Notifications`. Select `Vibrate` for message notifications subsection. Can you please check if this works?